# Disable word based suggestion in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to **disable word based suggestion**, it's annoying and useless in my opinion. For example Brackets will offer suggestion for variables, methods and language and **will not pollute the suggestion list** with all similar words written in file.

I just want code suggestion. I tried  `"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false`, but no luck. How to change that ? Thanks.

Example:
[image: Example]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try adding:

```
"javascript.nameSuggestions": false
```

Comment: Also "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top" can be added to put snippet suggestions on top of others. If anyone was looking for a way to do that.

Comment: The new setting is now `"javascript.suggest.names": false`

Comment: Or `"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false` to disable (globally?).

Answer (score 6):

You can use this setting:

```
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
```

Answer (score 3):

// Controls if suggestions should be accepted 'Enter' - in addition to 'Tab'. Helps to avoid ambiguity between inserting new lines or accepting suggestions.

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off"
```

from [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/505/how-to-disable-autocompletion-and-intellisense-in-microsoft-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 2):

In UI it's:

*Edit -> Perferences -> Settings -> Text Editor -> Suggestions -> Javascript > Suggest: Names*

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one as I had problems with javascript function snippet not being on top

```
  "editor.suggest.filteredTypes": {
     "keyword": false
  },
```