# I want to remove just string in vscode emmet

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, autofill, emmet

[image: 1]

I really want to remove just string of emmet (?)

i tried to remove by delete key, but it didn't work.

please let me know..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64688778/836330

Comment: Thanks Mark!, but this is what i want exactly..!! "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890967/disable-word-based-suggestion-in-visual-studio-code"