# How to disable code completion pop ups in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

What really annoys me is that this menu always appears when typing. It also covers most of the code. For me it is useless. Can you please tell me how to disable it?

[image: A picture of this menu]

I tried to disable this menu myself in the settings, but couldn't.

Comment: do you prefer to type those long identifiers or select them from a list and prevent typo errors, it encourages you to use descriptive names and not abbreviations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable word based suggestion in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890967/disable-word-based-suggestion-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another interesting link:
[Intellisense - Types of completions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions)

I added this to my `.vscode\settings.json`, and no longer get any suggestions:

```json
{
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": false,
    "editor.suggest.selectionMode": "never",
    "editor.suggest.showClasses": false,
    "editor.suggest.showColors": false,
    "editor.suggest.showConstants": false,
    "editor.suggest.showConstructors": false,
    "editor.suggest.showCustomcolors": false,
    "editor.suggest.showDeprecated": false,
    "editor.suggest.showEnumMembers": false,
    "editor.suggest.showEnums": false,
    "editor.suggest.showEvents": false,
    "editor.suggest.showFields": false,
    "editor.suggest.showFiles": false,
    "editor.suggest.showFolders": false,
    "editor.suggest.showFunctions": false,
    "editor.suggest.showIcons": false,
    "editor.suggest.showInterfaces": false,
    "editor.suggest.showIssues": false,
    "editor.suggest.showKeywords": false,
    "editor.suggest.showMethods": false,
    "editor.suggest.showModules": false,
    "editor.suggest.showOperators": false,
    "editor.suggest.showProperties": false,
    "editor.suggest.showReferences": false,
    "editor.suggest.showSnippets": false,
    "editor.suggest.showUnits": false,
    "editor.suggest.showTypeParameters": false,
    "editor.suggest.showStructs": false,
    "editor.suggest.showUsers": false,
    "editor.suggest.showValues": false,
    "editor.suggest.showVariables": false,
    "editor.suggest.showWords": false,
    "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false
}
```